# How can I add a choice field in django models through a form?

Tags: django

I have a choices field which has a set of limited number of choices like:

```
class Choices(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

This now is a foreign key to another model which has some data like:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.Charfield(max_length = 255)
    choice = models.ForeignKey(Choices, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I want that if a choice does not exist, one may be able to add a new Choice item while submitting the form and add it to the database, then the newly created choice can be used again.

Please help me accordingly.

Comment: So you Mean , You want to add both **ChoiceField** and **CharField** at the same time ?

Comment: Yes, such that if a choice field does not satisfy one can add a new choice with CharField